# CSS Aligning Tables Within Tables

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table that contains four other tables in a square.  I would like the inner four tables to align to the top left of the cells they are in but I would like the data in the cells of the inner tables to align in the center of their cells.  When I moved my attributes into CSS it all went awry.  I am probably over looking the obvious.

Also, all of my row lines and column lines have disappeared.

Basically I just need the correct CSS to accomplish this and restore the row and column lines.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Any html/css you could provide would be helpful.

Comment: `1.` More text less code.. `2.` What have you tried? `3.` Any pictorial or http://jsfiddle.net help you can provide?

Comment: Is the data going in the table tabular? Are you sure that these things are semantically tables? If not, perhaps they should be divs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date is in fact tabular and based on the little information you've provided is something like this fiddle roughly what you are going for?

[jsfiddle.net/qgSAJ/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/qgSAJ/8/)

If the data is not tabular, as  Patrick James McDougle divs would be undoubtedly the way to go